# Force browser to save password

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, browser, passwords, opera

I would like to make my Chrome/Opera to save login, password data without asking about it. It everytime asks if I want to save a password, but I want it to do this without any popups over time on different websites. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated here:
http://ccm.net/faq/40583-google-chrome-save-password-automatically-without-prompting
or here:
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-save-my-password-automatically-without-prompting-and-letting-users-know-when-someone-browses-to-any-site-in-Chrome

1. Open Google Chrome.
2. Type the following in the address bar and press the Enter key: chrome://flags/
3. Scroll to Save passwords automatically - Skip the passwords prompt and save passwords automatically and click on Enable.
4. Click on Relaunch Now.

Comment: +1 - the same thing works for `opera://flags` on Opera (use the filter to find it quickly), or `vivaldi://flags` on Vivaldi.

Comment: Note: This option appears to have been removed in 2017 ([link to the Chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=367690)). According to the link, the option was likely never intended to be used by regular users and [may not have even worked in the first place](https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B04zIcvgnrI2Q/?hl=en).