# How to in chrome save password without asking

Tags: google-chrome

How to force saving pswd without asking. chrome://flags/ does not work I cant find there "save passwords automatically" option or somethnig similar.

Comment: I'm guessing you were looking for the "enable-automatic-password-saving" flag. From what I've been able to find, this used to be a developer-only option that was completely removed back in 2017 (see [the Chromium bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=367690)). In any case, as Cyber_Agent said, there are obvious security issues with such functionality, so it's unlikely to be available for regular users.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t believe that an option like this would exist, and for good reason. Assuming you were able to force Chrome to save passwords without asking, what if you were to hand your computer to a friend and have them log into a site? Their password would be saved and you would be able to log into their account anytime you wanted. Imagine changing this setting in a browser in a public environment like a library. This would pose a serious security risk.

There might be a better answer to your question if you explain why you want the behavior you described.

Comment: Actually, there was in fact an option like that at some point in the past (see https://superuser.com/a/1027743). However, from what I've been able to gather, it was [originally intended for testing by the developers](https://codereview.chromium.org/256003003) and was probably not supposed to be available to regular users. In any case, it seems to have been removed at some point, but I haven't been able to find out when.

Comment: I absolutely agree with your reasoning though. The feature sounds like a huge security risk, and it's almost certainly a good thing that it's apparently not there anymore.

Comment: Firefox users have been enjoying a password manager that actually works for ages, without raising any flags.
And Chrome does f*ck up with your security when it wants to, e.g. when it hijacks your connection to Gmail, steals your identity, turns it into browser user profile, and reuses it whenever it "needs" it... without asking !

Comment: There's no good reason to prevent users from saving web site passwords.
Saving an encrypted password on your local computer on demand is much more secure than writing it down to some piece of paper, or to some random file sync'ed to your NSA monitored OneDrive account...
Also, typing any password on a public computer... oh well, where do we start ?